# Look for part of string in multidimensional object array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm having this object array:

```
stdClass Object (
   [ReadOpenCallsResult] => stdClass Object (
      [CallHeader] => Array (
         [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [DateChanged] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00 
            [DateCreated] => 2013-09-11T15:53:39.773 
            [Description] => Dubbel Test 
            [MessageCode] => C0000453325 
            [MessageId] => 83656 
            [Solved] => 
         ) 
         [1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [DateChanged] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00 
            [DateCreated] => 2013-09-11T13:40:54.077 
            [Description] => Test 
            [MessageCode] => C0000453324 
            [MessageId] => 83653 
            [Solved] => 
         ) 
      ) 
   ) 
)
```

And I have a function to look for a string in this array:

```
function in_object($val, $obj){
    if($val == ""){
        trigger_error("in_object expects parameter 1 must not empty", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_object($obj)){
        $obj = (object)$obj;
    }

    foreach($obj as $key => $value){
        if(!is_object($value) && !is_array($value)){
            if($value == $val){
                return true;
            }
        }
        else{
            return in_object($val, $value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, this function looks perfectly for a complete string. For example, if I search for 'Test' it returns me this part;

```
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [DateChanged] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00 
            [DateCreated] => 2013-09-11T13:40:54.077 
            [Description] => Test 
            [MessageCode] => C0000453324 
            [MessageId] => 83653 
            [Solved] => 
         )
```

**But** if I look for example for 'Dubbel' I want the function to return me:

```
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [DateChanged] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00 
            [DateCreated] => 2013-09-11T15:53:39.773 
            [Description] => Dubbel Test 
            [MessageCode] => C0000453325 
            [MessageId] => 83656 
            [Solved] => 
         )
```

But it doesn't. Only if I look for 'Dubbel Test'.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this, so I can search for parts of a string at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your == with a strpos(), like that:

```
function in_object($val, $obj){
if($val == ""){
    trigger_error("in_object expects parameter 1 must not empty", E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
}
if(!is_object($obj)){
    $obj = (object)$obj;
}

foreach($obj as $key => $value){
    if(!is_object($value) && !is_array($value)){
        if(strpos($value,$val)!==FALSE){
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        return in_object($val, $value);
    }
}
return false;
}
```

(Untested, but should work)

Comment: Wow, thanks! I knew about strpos but couldnt made it work directly on my object array. I owe you a beer!